# How to add filter / AOP method that cannot be removed without recompile?

Tags: java, spring, filter, spring-aop

My question would be: how do I add a servlet filter, or a Spring AOP method (or a third solution - you name it) that cannot be removed from a web application without recompiling?

I'd like to solve license handling that way, but if anyone modifies the web.xml or the Spring config, the protection is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Licence handling is definitely a cross-cutting concern which could (and IMO should) be modelled by means of AOP.

- I cannot say much about servlet filters, being unexperienced in this regard, but
- I know that Spring AOP is proxy-based, i.e. it does not modify the source code directly, which is not what you want.
- AspectJ, on the other hand, when used at compile-time (not via load-time weaving as is the usual approach in Spring), does compile aspect code right into your core class files, "baking" them into your byte code. This is probably what you want. I do not say it cannot be reverse-engineered - there always is this option - but the code would not run without the AspectJ runtime on the classpath and you could not remove the licencing aspects without recompilation. So this is the option I recomment for that purpose.

Interesting question, by the way.